# Declaring a variable belonging to a user-defined class in Perl 6

Tags: raku

When I declare a variable, whose value belongs to a built-in class, I simply write

```perl6
my Int $a;
```

But when I want to use a user-defined class, I [have to use](https://docs.perl6.org/language/classtut) `Classname.new`.

```perl6
my class House {
    has $.area is rw;
}

my $house1 = House.new;
$house1.area = 200;
say $house1.area;
```

So, my naïve question is, what's the reason of that difference? Why can't we simply write `my House $house1`?

My ultimate goal is to use an array whose values are instances of a user-defined class. How can I do the following correctly?

```perl6
my @houses ...;
@houses[10].area = 222;
```

Comment: There is no syntax to create a `House` literal, there is syntax to create an `Int` literal `200`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`my House $a` does the same as `my Int $a`.  It puts a restriction on the values that you can put in it.  If you look at the content of the variable, you will get the type object of that restriction.

There *is* a trick that you can use though, so you don't have to repeat the `House` bit: `my House $a .= new`, which is the equivalent of `my House $a = House.new`.

To get back to your question: yes, you can do that with some trouble:

```
class House {
    has $.area;
    multi method area(House:U \SELF:) is raw {
        (SELF = House.new).area
    }
    multi method area(House:D:) is raw {
        $!area
    }
}
my House @houses;
@houses[2].area = 42;
say @houses  # [(House) (House) House.new(area => 42)]
```

We create two candidates for the accessor method: one taking an undefined type object, and the other an instantiated object.  The first one modifies its invocant (assuming it to be a container that can be set), then calls the instantiated version of the method.  I'm leaving this as an exercise to the reader to turn this into an `Attribute` trait.

Answer (score 3):

When you write `my Int $a;` you will have a variable of type `Int`, but without value, or even container. The concrete value of `$a` will be `(Int)`.

The same with `my House $house;` - you will get `(House)` value.

In your case you have to initialize array's elements by some House value. For example:

```
my @houses = House.new() xx 11;
@houses[10].area = 222;
```

Comment: thanks! But I don't need to write `my $a = Int.new`, the question is — why?

Comment: You can write that.  There are some shorthand ways to create instances for some classes of object.  You could create your own shorthand methods for your objects if you like.  So you could say ```my $a = ``` for example

Comment: In code: `$a = 222` the constant `222` is a value which can be interpreted as `Int` value. On the other hand in code `my House $h = House.new(); my $n = $h;` variable `$h` describes a value of type `House`, and that value put in `$n` and you do not have to write `House.new()` for variable `$n`. I mean that `222` and `House.new` is the same things.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're missing the part that the compiler is doing some of the work for you. When you have a literal number, the parser recognizes it and constructs the right numeric object for it. There's a virtual and unseen `Int.new()` that has already happened for you in [rakudo/src/Perl6/Actions.nqp](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/Perl6/Actions.nqp). It's at the NQP level but it's the same idea.